# deixar imagem responsiva na horizontal, mas sem ser dimensionada, e sim cortada na horizontal

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde

Como deixar uma imagem responsiva, para que ela seja literalmente cortada na sua horizontal, para que remova o scrollbar horizontal da pagina, e nao fique com uma aparecia  "esmagada"

agradeço a quem ajudar, segue a baixo um exemplo, a imagem esta responsiva, mas queria remover o efeito de "esmagamento" da imagem, quero que ela seja cortada, e não redimensionalizada

```html
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
                <img alt="" class="form-image" border="0" src="https://www.jotform.com/uploads/natupote/form_files/SALADA2.png" height="800px" width="100%" />

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Terá que colocá-la como `background` pelo CSS

Comment: Pode me ensinar o comando? sou iniciante em prog voltado a web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa colocar a imagem como `background` de alguma `div`:

```css
.img-responsive {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/xRxFRSY.jpg') top center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-responsive">
</div>
```